# Rails - redirect to rendering partial from controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, partial-views

I am building a Single Page Application in rails. I am populating partials successfully in the root page on button clicks like this;

```
<div class="span12" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <%= link_to "Messages", "/messages", :class=>"btn btn-large btn-primary span12", :remote => true %>
</div>
```

This successfully renders the `_index.html.erb` partial. In this page there is a list of messages and links to delete them. When I delete them I get a Template Missing error because it is looking for index.html.erb and redirecting to `localhost:3000/messages` after deleting the messages. This is my destroy action, where it is being redirected after deleting the message

```
if @message.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Message was successfully deleted"
      redirect_to messages_path
else
      flash[:error] = "Message could not be deleted please try again"
      redirect_to messages_path
end
```

How can I make this action render the `_index.html.erb` partial again in `localhost:3000/`

Comment: which action renders the view that also includes `_index.html.erb` partial? you just redirect to that action rather than redirecting to index action.

Comment: there is only one view! and it renders a different partial by default on load. Other partials are rendered on button clicks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't render the index partial every time you delete a message. It should just be done in javascript.

I think you can do something like:

```
$(".messages").on(".message .destroy-link", "ajax:success", function(data) {
    var $link = $(this);
    $link.closest(".message").remove();
})
```

And in your controller you wouldn't redirect anywhere for `format.js`.